# What's the problem with simple EMA-crossover strategies?

Tags: foreign-exchange, cryptocurrency

I'm looking at charts of bitcoin here: https://bitcoinwisdom.com/markets/kraken/btceur
with the option of displaying a short term as well as a long term EMA.

It seems to me that if I were to buy bitcoin each time the short term EMA raises above the long term EMA, I would make money. I know this is obviously not the case since if it were, everyone would do it.

So in reality, what actually is the problem with these kind of simplistic strategies? The "strategy" seems to cover every relevant change in market price.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to answer this with any certainty, as the "problems" guggested by your question are many (they're not actually problems, they're failures of expectation - an EMA does exactly what it says - it provides an exponentially weighted average price). Here are a few possibilities:

1. Eye-balling a few charts simply doesn't come close to knowing whether something would work or be profitable in real trading. You'd need to code and then thoroughly backtest the strategy over thousands of instances with realistic deductions for slippage, spread, and commissions in order to have any confidence in its predictive ability.
2. Many markets are mean reverting, especially in shorter timeframes. This means they tend to regress back towards their average price rather than trend away from it.
3. The fact that a strategy worked historically is no guarantee that it will continue to be profitable (or, philosophically, the problem of induction: just because past futures resembled past pasts doesn't mean that future futures will).
4. An EMA is not actually that simplistic. A simple moving average is! And speaking generally from my own testing experience, simpler solutions tend to be more robust over the long haul; simple MA crossover systems tend to be better than EMA ones.
5. Averages are lagging calculations.
6. Traders and investors tend to gravitate towards complexity and sophistication, even when it does not serve them well. Your statement . . .

> I know this is obviously not the case since if it were, everyone would do it.

. . . simply isn't correct. There are plenty of trading strategies that were published decades ago that continue to be profitable to this day, and have made their users incredibly rich (eg trend following). But everyone isn't using them (typically because they're fixated on some 'holy grail' of easy returns).

Answer (score 0):

EMAs are a rolling average. They record price changes incorporating the most recent period thus a 3 ema is showing 3 most recent periods they thus adjust to recent ticks and contain little information about periods outside the set limits. 
In my experience EMAs tell a good story but don't predict too well, used in conjunction with other techniques they're okay. As a stamd alone indicator thoug, their record is mixed.